# What is WMTS' ScaleDenominator?

Tags: coordinates, scale, wmts

I am trying to write a program which will render tiles from EPSG2180-based WMTS server. Given coordinates of a point (WSG84 or EPSG2180, I can convert from one to another) I want to render a tile containing it.

Each `TileMatrix` has info about `TileWidth`/`Height`, `MatrixWidth`/`Height`, `TopLeftCorner` and I understand what they mean. However, they don't seem sufficient to translate lat/lon to row/column. Apart from those each TileMatrix has mysterious `ScaleDenominator` value.

What is `ScaleDenominator` and what is the relationship between it and other values describing `TileMatrix`? How can I use it to translate lat/lon to tile's row/column?

Comment: The standard http://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=35326 tries to give an answer to both of your questions. Please quote the parts that remains unclear for you.

Comment: Everything is clear now, thank you very much! As an amateur I didn't even think of googling "wmts standard", I didn't expect such doc to be so human-friendly. Thanks again!

Comment: @hugo please add and accept an answer to help out future users who have the sam equestion

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Standard linked by @user30184 ([portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=35326](https://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=35326)) explicitly and precisely defines `ScaleDenominator` in section 6.1 "Tile matrix set – the geometry of the tiled space":

> The scale denominator is defined with respect to a "standardized rendering pixel size" of 0.28 mm × 0.28 mm (millimeters).

Scale of tiled map is 1:`ScaleDenominator`. **Each pixel is assumed to be 0.28mm**, which allows to calculate span of each tile in meters by multiplying `TileWidth` (or `TileHeight`) by `ScaleDenominator * 0.00028`.

Knowing real-world size of each tile in meters (and knowing that the CRS used is EPSG 2180, which uses meter as its base unit), I was finally able to determine size of the whole matrix and choose appropriate tile for given coordinates.

Comment: For those of us using EPSG:27700 (British National Grid): to get the **row** take the `TopLeftCorner[1]` and subtract the **Northings** before floor dividing (`//`) by `TileHeight`*`ScaleDenominator`*0.00028. To get the **column** take the **Eastings** and subtract the `TopLeftCorner[0]` before floor dividing by `TileWidth`*`ScaleDenominator`*0.00028.