# QWC2 - How to calculate WMTS Resolutions

Tags: wmts, qgis-web-client

I am trying to add this WMTS as a background layer in QWC2.

https://geoegl.msp.gouv.qc.ca/carto/wmts?SERVICE=WMTS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&VERSION=1.3.0

In the GetCapabilities results I see 22 scale denominators that I am trying to convert into resolution values for my themesConfig.json file in QWC2.

I have been searching on internet for days now but I can't find any info or formula on how to do this.

Does such a formula actually exist ?  Or is there a way I haven't seen to make QWC2 figure out the resolutions itself ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ian's answer was quite helpful (thanks a lot) but it's still not a complete solution since we don't know the value of "size" in resolutions[z] = size / Math.pow(2, z).

It did however put me on the right track.  Here's how I figured out the resolutions to use in my QWC2 themesConfig.json file.

The themesConfig.json example on the QWC2 download site shows the resolutions for a WMTS that is in the same projection.

```
 {
    "type": "wmts",
    "url": "https://wxs.ign.fr/pratique/geoportail/wmts",
    "title": "IGN",
    "name": "GEOGRAPHICALGRIDSYSTEMS.MAPS",
    "format": "image/jpeg",
    "style": "normal",
    "originX": -20037508,
    "originY": 20037508,
    "projection": "EPSG:3857",
    "resolutions": [
      156543.03392804097,
      78271.51696402048,
      39135.75848201024,
      19567.87924100512,
      9783.93962050256,
      4891.96981025128,
      2445.98490512564,
      1222.99245256282,
      611.49622628141,
      305.748113140705,
      152.8740565703525,
      76.43702828517625,
      38.21851414258813,
      19.109257071294063,
      9.554628535647032,
      4.777314267823516,
      2.388657133911758,
      1.194328566955879
    ],
    "tileSize": [256, 256],
    "requestEncoding": "KVP",
    "tileMatrixSet": "PM",
    "tileMatrixPrefix": "",
    "thumbnail": "ign.png",
    "attribution": "<a href=\"http://www.geoportail.fr/\" target=\"_blank\"><img src=\"https://api.ign.fr/geoportail/api/js/latest/theme/geoportal/img/logo_gp.gif\"></a>"
  }
```

So I tested my wmts with these resolutions and it worked until I got to a certain zoom lever.  I figured the reason was the example has 18 resolutions but my WMTS has 22 scale denominators.

Since things worked for the 18 resolutions I had, the solution was as simple as doing a reverse calculation.  I took the first 3 resolutions from the sample and divided them by the first 3 scale denominators I got from GetCapabilities.

```
156543.03392804097 / 559082264.02871787548065185547 = 0.00028
 78271.51696402048 / 279541132.01435887813568115234 = 0.00028
 39135.75848201024 / 139770566.00717940926551818848 = 0.00028
```

So clearly 0.00028 is a constant, all I had to do was multiply the last 4 scale denominators from my GetCapabilities by 0.00028 to get the 4 resolutions I was missing which are

```
      0.597164283
      0.298582142
      0.149291071
      0.074645535
```

The resolutions section of themesConfig.json for my WMTS is as follows, it works perfectly.

```
 "resolutions": [
      156543.03392804097,
      78271.51696402048,
      39135.75848201024,
      19567.87924100512,
      9783.93962050256,
      4891.96981025128,
      2445.98490512564,
      1222.99245256282,
      611.49622628141,
      305.748113140705,
      152.8740565703525,
      76.43702828517625,
      38.21851414258813,
      19.109257071294063,
      9.554628535647032,
      4.777314267823516,
      2.388657133911758,
      1.194328566955879,
      0.597164283,
      0.298582142,
      0.149291071,
      0.074645535
    ],
```

Comment: 0.28mm is the assumed pixel width, see https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/315989/87572

Answer (score 3):

Ideally, your client should calculate all it needs from the getcapabilties response. But, looking at the [OpenLayer example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/wmts.html) the following code is usually used to calculate the resolutions array (assuming you are in EPGS:3857):

```
for (var z = 0; z < 14; ++z) {
      // generate resolutions and matrixIds arrays for this WMTS
      resolutions[z] = size / Math.pow(2, z);
      matrixIds[z] = z;
 }
```